# Как удалить uwsgi скомпилированный из исходников

Tags: python, uwsgi

Устанавливал так:

```
wget https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
cd uwsgi-2.0.15
make PROFILE=nolang
PYTHON=python3.5.3 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python35"
```

Пробывал удалить

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --build uninstall

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 1601, in <module>
    uc = uConf(bconf, is_cflags)
  File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 653, in __init__
    self.config.readfp(open_profile(filename))
  File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 631, in open_profile
    return open(filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'buildconf/uninstall.ini'
```

В каталоге buildconf нет никаих правил для удаления.

```
ls buildconf

all.ini       django.ini     lib.ini      php.ini     pypyonly.ini  servlet.ini
asyncio.ini   embedded.ini   lua.ini      plonly.ini  pyring.ini    travis.ini
base.ini      erlang.ini     luap.ini     ppa.ini     pyuwsgi.ini   unbit.ini
cgi.ini       gccgo.ini      minimal.ini  psgi.ini    rack.ini      unbitstaff.ini
core.ini      gevent.ini     modular.ini  pyerl.ini   rados.ini     uwsgi.it.ini
coroae.ini    glusterfs.ini  mono.ini     pylua.ini   rbonly.ini    v8.ini
coverity.ini  gridfs.ini     nolang.ini   pyonly.ini  ring.ini
default.ini   jwsgi.ini      package.ini  pypy.ini    ruby2.ini
```

В самом Makefile:

```
PYTHON := python

all:
        $(PYTHON) uwsgiconfig.py --build $(PROFILE)

clean:
        $(PYTHON) uwsgiconfig.py --clean

check:
        $(PYTHON) uwsgiconfig.py --check

plugin.%:
        $(PYTHON) uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/$* $(PROFILE)

%:
        $(PYTHON) uwsgiconfig.py --build $@
```

Comment: На будущее можно пользоваться [Checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/CheckInstall) - при установке он отследит что и куда установилось, потом сам создаст .deb пакет и его можно будет легко удалить и не гадать, какие еще файлы забыл.

Comment: @m9_psy Спасибо, действительно нужная вещь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так 
 
`python uwsgiconfig.py --clean
rm /usr/local/bin/uwsgi`

Далее просто поставил uwsgi 2.0.14 для python 3.5.2 из пакета debian

```
which uwsgi
/usr/bin/uwsgi
```

P.S. впредь никогда не буду собирать из исходников командой `make install` 
Пользуйтесь, например [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/CheckInstall). (`checkinstall make install`). Он собирает всё в пакет, который потом можно будет легко удалить.